# how to assign different variables in a single data table in uipath

Tags: uipath

[image]

how to assign two variable like Part_url, Part_Number in a single data table.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [GetRowItem Activity](https://activities.uipath.com/docs/get-row-item) to assign variables to columns in your data table. While iterating the data table, use the GetRowItem activity with a specific column name like "Part_url" and an output as a new variable. Here are two screenshots showing how I assign several variables while iterating a data table using the column names in the data table and the GetRowItem activity:

[image: Example of workflow & properties]